# Upload files from a Gentran server to box.com FTPS

Tags: ssl, file-upload, ftp, box, ftps

One of our clients wants to automate file upload via FTPS from their Gentran server. And they are using a Gentran server. We use box.com as a secure place to exchange files. They ask us about SSL key, but obviously we don't have it for box.com. Previously, we were successful in providing FTPS access to our folders to other clients, but they used some tool like Filezilla. 

Here are some links that box.com can do:
[here](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Your-Content/Using-Box-with-FTP/ta-p/312) and [here](https://community.box.com/t5/Managing-Your-Content/I-m-having-trouble-using-FTP-with-Box/ta-p/323)

What is the solution? Could we get some box.com public SSL key that they can use? Or any other ways for them to setup automated file upload to box.com?
 Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer appeared to be easier than I expected.. Asking questions never hurts..
So I just emailed my question to the box.com supports and very shortly I received a response with their SSL cert.